# Swift, Stop Images from loading in table View

Tags: swift, tableview

Here I load my images, I want to stop the images from loading when I click on the path. How can this be done? I tried setting the URL to nil but that didn't work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as? CustomCell
            let pintrestsUrl = pintrest[indexPath.row].urls?.thumb
            Library().parseImages(ImagesUrlArrayPath: pintrestsUrl!, completion: { (image) -> Void in
                if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: pintrestsUrl as AnyObject ) as? UIImage {
                    cell?.ImageView.image = imageFromCache
                }
            })
            return cell!
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            // stop images from loading

        }
```

EDIT -- added ParseImages Function

```
func parseImages(ImagesUrlArrayPath: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage)-> Void) {
        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: ImagesUrlArrayPath as AnyObject ) as? UIImage {
            completion(imageFromCache)
        }
        else
        {
        if let imageURL = URL(string: (ImagesUrlArrayPath)){
            DispatchQueue.global().async{
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                if let data = data{
                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
//                    let image = imageToCache
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: ImagesUrlArrayPath as AnyObject)
                        completion(imageToCache!)
                        print("sucess")
                        //cell?.videoImageView.image = image //?.resizeImage(targetSize: size)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try to keep the request in the table view cell and cancel the request in your tableView cellForRowAt method

Comment: I need to maintain the Library because of its kind of a requirement. Maybe I have to call the library and stop the processing?

Comment: keep a map of requests in the library and using the url string as key so you can fetch the request and cancel it

Comment: How will do this? I will add parse Images into this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this awhile back
You have to set the images to nil before loading new images on them